# Layout selection on app launch

Tags: android

I'm trying to create an app. The app checks for a shared preference value on start-up.

1) if shared preference is set, it should start activity1
2) if shared preference is not set, it should start activity2

So what layout do I use for the main activity to display the screen? The main activity is used to start either activity1 or activity2. Is there a way to launch activity1 or activity2 from main activity without using any layout for the main activity?

I don't intend to display the main activity to the user. The interest in in showing either activity1 or activity2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Fragments would probably the best solution, because like this, you don't have to start another Activity from your starting Activity. In your MainActivity, just define a layout that contains a Fragment placeholder. On start, if the shared preference is set, show Fragment1, if not, show Fragment2.

Layout of the MainActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And in the `onCreate` of your MainActivity create the corresponding Fragment and add it to your layout:

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
Fragment fragment = manager.findFragmentByTag("someTag");
// only create a new fragment, if it is not created yet
if(fragment==null){
  if(preferenceIsSet){
    fragment = new Fragment1();
  }else{
    fragment = new Fragment2();
  }
}
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, "someTag");
transaction.commit();
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 0):

read up on [starting an activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

basically, your main task should:

1) create an Intent for activity1 or 2 depending on the value/existence of your shared preference

2) run StartActivity(newIntent)

3) run finish()

In in your manifest use android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" and you will not require a layout.